# Oracle PL/SQL - parameterizing SAMPLE clause in SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle related question. I would like to select a random sample out of a view or table in such a way that the [SAMPLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2105143) clause is parameterized.

Given the following table.

```
 CREATE TABLE FOO AS
        (SELECT     LEVEL AS ID
                   FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 101
        );
```

The following construct works, using a literal parameter in the SAMPLE clause.

```
SELECT ID FROM FOO SAMPLE (15); -- this will get a 15% sample
```

However,

```
DECLARE
    N NUMBER := 50;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN
    ( SELECT ID FROM FOO SAMPLE (N) -- <<< this won't work
    )
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( r.ID );
    END LOOP;
END;
```

This block blows up when we put a parameter in the `SAMPLE` clause. It compiles and works if we put it a literal.

But if it is a variable, I get the following:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 33:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Any ideas? I'm racking by brains where the syntax gets broken.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax does not allow a variable there.

One workaround would be to construct the `SELECT` statement dynamically.  For example:

```
declare
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
  n number := 5;
begin
  -- replace "mtl_system_items" with your table...
  open l_rc FOR 'select count(*) from mtl_system_items sample (' || n || ')';
  -- replace call to RETURN_RESULT with whatever processing you want
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_rc);
end;
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, but I guess I have no choice. Thanks for answering!